# Yet another question about turning off auto-maximize

Tags: 14.04

**How does one disable the auto-maximize when one drags a window to the top of the screen in Ubuntu 14.04?**  I've spent a while combing the many many answers to nearly identical questions and none of the responses have worked for me, largely because it seems I have not even installed most of the apps/packages that the answers start from (e.g., I don't have Compiz installed, and therefore don't have CCSM).  Yet this annoying feature is enabled **somewhere**.

Comment: Actually, unless you are running `gnome` you *are* running `compiz`.  `compiz` is the program which runs behind `unity` the display manager.  You may not have installed `ccsm` however.

Answer (score 0):

The window manager tweaks option is called: "Automatically tile windows when moving towards the edge". Find that one, in the Accessibility tab, and un-tick it.